# apt-get error while installing software

Tags: software-installation, apt

I was able to update packages using

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

but when I tried to install telnet using

`$ sudo apt-get install telnet`,

I get the following errors

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error , aborting:
too-long line or missing new line in /var/lib/dpkg/diversions'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I'm unable to install any other software as well
Neither could I find any online resources which solved the problem.
I'm currently using debian os, raspberry pi model b+.
Please help me out

Comment: Maybe this helps you, but I've not tried it myself: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1319791

Answer (score 1):

Copy the old diversions instead of the current:

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/diversions /var/lib/dpkg/diversions.bak
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/diversions-old /var/lib/dpkg/diversions
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and managed to fix it (? hopefully) by emptying the /var/lib/dpkg/diversions file:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/diversions ./diversions.backup
sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/diversions
```

*on a pi 3 with Raspbian Jessie.*

Comment: @Fabian pi 3 with Raspbian Jessie

Answer (score -1):

The problem is likely dpkg

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a   
sudo apt-get clean
sudo dpkg-divert --list 
sudo apt-get check
sudo apt-get install -f
```